# I have an issue with _spawn

Tags: spawn

I was writing a python script on making it so it barks. I wrote this and it had a 'spawn protected' error.

Code:
`# Shift the pitch of the bark sound bark = bark._spawn(bark.raw_data, overrides={'frame_rate': int(bark.frame_rate * (2.0 ** pitch_shift / 12.0))}) bark = bark.set_frame_rate(44100)` 
Output:
'Access to a protected member _spawn of a client class'

Comment: We have no idea what `bark` is here...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.